# Private repository of GIT integration with JIRA

Tags: git, jira

I have integrated GIT repositories with Jira ticket as instructed in confluence.atlassian.com . I am unable to see reflection in JIRA tickets about my commits, pull request branches etc, only for private GIT repositories. Any Suggestions?

For non private repositories things are working as expected.

Comment: Check whether your commit message/branch name contains your jira task id or not because jira needs your jira id somewhere either in the commit message or you need to create branch name with your jira id or you can create your branch from your jira itself.

Comment: Yes I am following all the rules, such as creating branch name with jira task ID, During commit I commit with JIRA task ID. This is working fine for other non private projects/ repositories. I have problem only if GIT Projects are private